# Why do these links exceed the width?

Tags: html, css, dom

How can we explain that these links exceed the 200px width:

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px; }
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;  }
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

**whereas, if we add a newline after each `</a>`, it doesn't:**

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px; }
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;  }
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a>
<a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
<a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
<a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
<a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
<a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
<a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

**What is the usual good practice to not be trapped in such corner cases?**

Comment: I think it's because you didn't left a white space between the anchors so the browser doesn't have a point to break the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't leave a white space between the anchors so the browser doesn't have a point to break the string.
Adding some space between the anchors should work:

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px; }
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;  }
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Because there is no space between the `a` tags and browser can't break `a` tag in new line.you can use of `word-wrap`[(more...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) or `word-break`[(more...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) .

**A)** Use of `word-wrap`:

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px;word-wrap: break-word;};
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;  }
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

**B)** Use of `word-break`:

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px;word-break: break-all;};
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;  }
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

**C)** Other way is put a space between the `a` tags.

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px;};
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a> <a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `a{display:inline-block;}` for inline elements a

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px; }
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;  }
a{
display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
```

to your .tag class, the links will stay within the bounds of the .small parent div.

```css
.small { background-color: red; width: 200px; }
.tag { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05); margin-right: 10px;width:100%;display:inline-block;  }
```

```html
<div class="small">
<a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:block;` will do magic you need

```css
    .small { background-color: red; width: 200px; }
    .tag {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
      /*margin-right: 10px;*/ /* Remove Margin from Right*/
      display:block; /* Line Break in CSS */
    }
```

```html
    <div class="small">
    <a class="date" href="blah">2 January 2017</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a><a class="tag" href="blah">#foooooo</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can edit and use a "code snippet" to make it easily runnable in browser.